# Defining a flexible structure in Prolog

Tags: data-structures, prolog

Well, I'm a bit new to Prolog, so my question is on Prolog pattern/logic.

I have an relationship called tablet. It has many parameters, such as name, operationSystem, ramCapacity, etc. I have many objects/predicates of this relationship, like

```
tablet(
         name("tablet1"),
         operatingSystem("ios"),
         ramCapacity(1024),
         screen(
                  type("IPS"),
                  resolution(1024,2048)
               )
      ).

tablet(
         name("tablet2"),
         operatingSystem("android"),
         ramCapacity(2048),
         screen(
                  type("IPS"),
                  resolution(1024,2048),
                  protected(yes)
               ),
          isSupported(yes)
      ).
```

And some others similar relationships, BUT with different amounts of parameters. Some of attributes in different objects I do not need OR I have created some tablets, and one day add one more field and started to use it in new tablets.

There are two questions:

1. I need to use the most flexible structure as possible in prolog. Some of the tablets have attributes/innerPredicates and some do not, but They are all tablets.
2. I need to access data the easiest way, for example find all tablets that have ramCapacity(1024), not include ones that do not have this attributes.
3. I do need to change some attributes' values in the easiest way. For example query - change ramCapacity to 2048 for tablet that has name "tablet1".
4. If it's possible it should be pretty to read in a word editor :)

Is this structure flexible? Should I use another one? Do I need additional rules to manipulate this structure? Is this structure easy to change with query?(I keep this structure in a file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of attributes is not fixed and needs to be so flexible, consider to represent these items as in option lists, like this:

```
tablet([name=tablet1,
        operating_system=ios,
        ram_capacity=1024,
        screen=screen([type="IPS",
                       resolution = res(1024,2048)])]).

tablet([name=tablet2,
        operating_system=android,
        ram_capacity=2048,
        screen=screen([type="IPS",
                       resolution = res(1024,2048)]),
        is_supported=yes]).
```

You can easily query and arbitrarily extend such lists. Example:

```
?- tablet(Ts), member(name=tablet2, Ts).
Ts = [name=tablet2, operating_system=android, ram_capacity=2048, screen=screen([type="IPS", resolution=res(..., ...)]), is_supported=yes] ;
false.
```

Notice also the common Prolog `naming_convention_to_use_underscores_for_readability` instead of `mixingCasesAndMakingEverythingExtremelyHardToRead`.

Comment: Is it easy to update some attributes with a query, like : all tablets with operating_system=android change screen resolution to 2048,2048?

Comment: You can do this with a query like: `?- tablet(Ts0), member(operating_system=android, Ts0), select(screen=screen(Scs0), Ts0, Ts1), select(resolution=_, Scs0, Scs1), Ts = [screen=screen([resolution=res(2048,2048)|Scs1])|Ts1].`, obtaining as `Ts` the updated attribute list. Appending `portray_clause(tablet(Ts))` at the end prints it in a way that can readily replace the previous definition of that item.

Comment: Oh, thanks, and the last question, how to insert the attribute if it is missed?